# How can I verify in C# if a folder has "Security" to "Everyone - Full Control: Allow"?

Tags: c#

How can I verify in C# if a folder has set "Security" to "Everyone - Full Control: Allow?

[image]

Many Thanks!

Comment: [Directory.GetAccessControl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getaccesscontrol)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be as easy as

```
var ctrl = new DirectoryInfo(@"D:\something").GetAccessControl();

var everyone = new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.WorldSid, null);

var accessRules = ctrl.GetAccessRules(true, true, typeof(SecurityIdentifier));

var result = accessRules
   .Cast<FileSystemAccessRule>()
   .Any(rule =>
      rule.IdentityReference.Value == everyone.Value && // check everyone
      rule.AccessControlType == AccessControlType.Allow && // check allow
      rule.FileSystemRights == FileSystemRights.FullControl); // check full control
```

<sub>***Note** : This is windows only (obviously), and you might need `System.IO.FileSystem.AccessControl` nuget*</sub>

---

**Additional Resources**

[Directory.GetAccessControl Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getaccesscontrol?view=netframework-4.8)

> Returns the Windows access control list (ACL) for a directory.

[SecurityIdentifier Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.principal.securityidentifier?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0)

> Represents a security identifier (SID) and provides marshaling and
> comparison operations for SIDs.

[WellKnownSidType Enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.principal.wellknownsidtype?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0)

> Indicates a SID that matches everyone.

[DirectoryObjectSecurity.GetAccessRules(Boolean, Boolean, Type) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.accesscontrol.directoryobjectsecurity.getaccessrules?view=net-5.0)

> Gets a collection of the access rules associated with the specified
> security identifier.